R -- After sorting columns of matrix, the column means now differ for some columns... why?
So, I wanted to plot the cumulative sums of the columns when ordered according to magnitude. This ended up producing a plot that didn't look like what I expected to see. My expectations could be wrong but what's certainly the case is that after sorting for a handful of columns the column means have changed. And I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
As it happens, this was a fake data exercise so you can see for yourselves:
df.exercise = .2
set.seed(78455823)

toad = matrix(rt(1000 * 4000, df.exercise), ncol = 1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
  toad.sort[, i] = toad[order(abs(toad[, i])), i]
}

which(colMeans(toad) != colMeans(toad.sort))
which(colSums(toad) != colSums(toad.sort))

loop.sums = loop.sums.sort = numeric(1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
 loop.sums.sort[i] = sum(toad.sort[, i])
 loop.sums[i] = sum(toad[, i])
}

which(loop.sums.sort != loop.sums)
which(loop.sums.sort != colSums(toad.sort))
which(loop.sums != colSums(toad))


It is also the case that colSums(toad) / 4000 doesn't result in colMeans(toad).
So, does anyone know why the disagreement(s) is(are) happening?

Floating point representation issue. BTW, you can easier sort your matrix using apply(toad, 2, sort).

Floating point? Damn, I should've been able to figure that out. I'm going to have to think about what to do now...  maybe the thing I was trying before this did actually make sense.

Well spotted! It is one of the quirks of floating point arithmetic that unlike in conventional mathematics the operator + cares about the order in which it is presented with data (and their signs and magnitudes).
There are a couple of easy ways around it - always sum into a higher precision variable which will have enough room in the mantissa to handle the resulting sum. Reals or integers into a double precision accumulator, doubles into proper long doubles (true 80 bit ones essential - sometimes long double == double on eg. MSC compiler or Intel in MS compatibility mode is 64 bit).
Presort the array so that the smallest values are processed first will give the most accurate conventional result. Conversely presorting the array so that the largest ones are summed first will give the least accurate result.
Various schemes are possible like summing the ordered values in pairs recursively (padding with zeroes as needed). That brings the error down nicely and can be quicker than naeive summation.
The final method which will get a much better result (provided that your optimising complier doesn't wreck it) is Kahan Summation which carries forward a compensation value c representing the errors made in each addition. It exploits a precise way of given a, b computing a pair c, d such that a + b == c + d exactly. This is a simple C code version of it (converted from the pseudo code reference - possibly subject to typos).
double KahanSum(double *x, int n)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  float c = 0.0;   // running compensation for lost low-order bits.
  // sum is potentially big, y small, so low-order digits of y are lost.

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
     float t, y;       
     var y = x[i] - c;    // c is zero the first time around.
     t = sum + y;         // (t - sum) cancels the high-order part of y;
    
     c = (t - sum) - y;   // subtracting y recovers negative (low part of y)
     sum = t;
     // Algebraically, c should always be zero (but in IEEE754 FP math it isn't). 
     // Beware of overly-aggressive optimizing compilers! --ffast-math breaks this code
     // The lost low part will be added to y in a fresh attempt.
  }
  return sum;
}

I have used this in the past and I think followed the formulation exactly as above verbatim. But typing it in now as an answer here I wonder why the return value is not sum - c. It seems to me that loop termination occurs with a final pending compensation c that isn't applied. What do others think?
There are a couple of newer more complex algorithms with even better correction but slower algorithms by Nuemaier and another by Klein also on the same Wiki page. Kahan's method deserves to be better known (particularly useful on compilers which do not provide support for hardware 80 bit floating point).

You should be aware of the value in toad. As you can see, the max value in your example is
> max(toad)
[1] 4.205729e+29

which is already too big if when you take colSums, where the sum loses its precision and deviates a lot already.
